# EF Code First Anybody have a list of possible DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

Does anyone have a list of all possible System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?

It seems like every time I read an article there are new ones I've never seen before. But I've never seen a list of all of them.

Thanks a bunch!
Eric

Comment: have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx

Comment: I hadn't seen this before. Seems like a good list... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also the new DataAnnotations which shipped with EF 4.1: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(VS.103).aspx

Comment: @Eranga's list is bigger than this one. I guess this illustrates the problem I was facing. Each time I think I have the list I see yet another annotation. As always, thanks.